# Python Selenium not able to find element for Create New Account button on website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Here is my code so far, note that the web page loads up with a captcha. I countered this with adding a time.sleep so I can run tests. When I try to submit the form by submitting "Create new account", I get an error saying the element has no attribute for 'submit'. I tried finding the element using xpath, css_selectos, tags, class names, etc.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.bstn.com/en/register/address')
time.sleep(35)

elam = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("[value='Create new account']")
elam.Submit()
```

Comment: Are you trying to click on create new account button?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to click on Create new account button after filling information then please find below `xpath` to click on it

```
     from selenium import webdriver
     from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
     from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
     from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
     from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='button radius charcheck-submit']"))).click()
```

**Another solution with action class**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

    actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
    submit = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='button radius charcheck-submit']")))
    actionChains.move_to_element(submit).click().perform()
```

**Working code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
# browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.bstn.com/en/register/address')
time.sleep(35)
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='button radius charcheck-submit']"))).click()
```

Comment: It didn't work, can you test the code yourself and send the whole thing over? I get this error: AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'element_to_be_clickable'

Comment: You need to import the following:                                                               ```from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait```
```from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC```
```from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By```
```from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException```